# How can I update without changing the previous value?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, api

I'm trying to create a CRUD using Reactjs + MySQL node modules, but I've got a problem wherein when I tried to update, I should update all fields,

Table

[image: List]

So in this image, I've got a table, if I click the question, I can able to edit it.

[image: Update Page]

This is my update form,

[image: Updated Table]

so this is what my table looks like, I only left question_order, and in that case, it should be stay the same and will not be removed.

Front.jsx

```
  const [updateQuestion, setUpdateQuestion] = useState({
    question: '',
    question_order: '',
    type: "Single",
    toggle: "0",
})

  

  useEffect(() =>{
    setLoading(true)
    const getSIngleQuestion = async () =>{
      try {
        const res = await publicRequest.get(`/employees/find/${id}`)
        setGetSingleData(res.data)
        setLoading(false)

      } catch (error) {
        console.log({message:error.message})
      }
    }
    getSIngleQuestion()
  },[id, setGetSingleData,location, setUpdateQuestion])

return(

    <TextField label="Question" defaultValue={getSingleData?.question || ""} variant="outlined"   name="question" onChange={handleAnswerChange}    /> 
    
    <TextField name="question_order"  label="Question Order"  defaultValue={getSingleData?.question_order || ""}    type="number"  onChange={handleAnswerChange}   inputProps={{ min: 1 }} />

)
```

backend.js

```
export const updateQuestion = async (req,res) =>{
  const id = req.params.id;
  const { question, question_order, type, toggle } = req.body;

  const query = `UPDATE employeesquestionpart1 SET question = ?, question_order = ?, type = ?, toggle = ? WHERE idemployeesquestionpart1 = ?`;
  const values = [question, question_order, type, toggle, id];

  try {
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(query, values);
    if (rows.affectedRows > 0) {
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Record updated successfully' });
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'Record not found' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating record:', error);
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error updating record' });
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
const handleAnswerChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
     if (name === "toggle") {
      setUpdateQuestion((prev) => ({...prev, [name]: value === "1" ? "1" : "0" }));
    } else {
      setUpdateQuestion((prev) => ({...prev, [name]: value }));
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you post the `handleAnswerChange` method implementation and where you call the `updateQuestion` end-point?

Comment: @lpizzinidev, please check, i already updated